# NetworkPolicy can not restrict Ingress from UI

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a flask service (6 replicas) and ui (3 replicas) deployed using a `kind:Deployment` but when i add a calico NetworkPolicy like this:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: application-network-policy
  namespace: team-prod-xyz
  labels:
    app: application-network-policy
spec:
  podSelector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: xyz-svc
      run: xyz-svc
  ingress:
  - ports:
    - port: 8000
    from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: xyz-ui
  egress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

My flask service goes like this if i directly access it

```
504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.15.3
```

which is probably expected but my UI can not hit the endpoints as well.

Why is that?

EDIT 2: Kubernetes and Ingress Information

Kubernetes Version -

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.8", GitCommit:"211047e9a1922595eaa3a1127ed365e9299a6c23", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T12:02:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/xyz-mongodb-replicaset-0                    1/1     Running     0          10d
pod/xyz-mongodb-replicaset-1                    1/1     Running     0          7d
pod/xyz-mongodb-replicaset-2                    1/1     Running     0          6d23h
pod/xyz-svc-7b589fbd4-25qd6                     1/1     Running     0          20h
pod/xyz-svc-7b589fbd4-9n8jh                     1/1     Running     0          20h
pod/xyz-svc-7b589fbd4-r5q9g                     1/1     Running     0          20h
pod/xyz-ui-7d6f44b57b-8s4mq                     1/1     Running     0          3d20h
pod/xyz-ui-7d6f44b57b-bl8r6                     1/1     Running     0          3d20h
pod/xyz-ui-7d6f44b57b-jwhc2                     1/1     Running     0          3d20h
pod/mongodb-backup-check                        1/1     Running     0          20h

NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/xyz-mongodb-replicaset   ClusterIP   None          <none>        27017/TCP   10d
service/xyz-prod-service         ClusterIP   10.3.92.123   <none>        8000/TCP    20h
service/xyz-prod-ui              ClusterIP   10.3.49.132   <none>        80/TCP      10d

--Deployment--
--Replicasset--
--Statefulset--
```

My ingress looks like -

```
Name:             xyz-prod-svc
Namespace:        prod-xyz
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  prod terminates xyz.prod.domain.com
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  xyz.prod.domain.com
                            /           xyz-prod-u:80 (10.7.2.4:80,10.7.4.22:80,10.7.5.24:80)
                            /project    xyz-prod-servic:8000 (10.7.2.15:8000,10.7.5.10:8000,10.7.5.10:8000 + 3 more...)
                            /trigger    xyz-prod-servic:8000 (10.7.2.15:8000,10.7.5.10:8000,10.7.5.10:8000 + 3 more...)
                            /kpi        xyz-prod-servic:8000 (10.7.2.15:8000,10.7.5.10:8000,10.7.5.10:8000 + 3 more...)
                            /feedback   xyz-prod-servic:8000 (10.7.2.15:8000,10.7.5.10:8000,10.7.5.10:8000 + 3 more...)
```

Do I have to specify my Ingress in the podSelector option of my Network Policy?

So far my Network Policy looks like this -

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: application-network-policy
  namespace: app-prod-xyz
  labels:
    app: application-network-policy
spec:
  podSelector: 
    matchLabel:
        run: xyz-svc
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: xyz-ui
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: application-health-check
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: xyz-ui
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: xyz-mongodb-replicaset
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongodb-replicaset
```

EDIT 1: I learned that we need to expose port 8000 using a config map before the network policy.

EDIT 3: With UI I mean the deployment done with the node image. I have to check whether the request is being sent through the UI pod or directly to the svc pod.

Comment: Hi @technazi, Could You provide informations about your kubernetes version and ingress? What You mean by "ui"? Problem still occurs or it's fixed after your EDIT?

Comment: You miss "s" in your spec.podSelector, it should be matchLabels instead of matchLabel, let me know if it works after You changed it or the problem still occurs. – jt97

Comment: I will close this question as xyz-ui service does not talk directly to the xyz-svc (backend service), It talks to it via Ingress and that is the reason if I add podSelector as xyz-svc and Ingress allowed xyz-ui it does not work since the requests are not coming through the ui service but the Ingress.

Comment: @jt97 Sorry it was a typo here, it did not work after adding the 's'. Thanks for your help. Let me know if i can provide more information to the above comment.